# How to compare collection item using createCriteria?

Tags: grails, createcriteria

Registration domain has a collection of discounts.

```
static hasMany = [ discounts: Discount]
```

I want to extract all Registrations that have a particular discount applied.

In the following code i want to get all registrations whose collection has the discount of id disid. How can i achieve that? I appreciate any help!

```
def disid = Discount.get(1).id

def regs = Registration.createCriteria().list(){

            eq('compositeEvent', cod.compositeEvent)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def disid = Discount.get(1).id

def regs = Registration.withCriteria() {
    discounts  {
        eq 'id', disid
    }
}
```

See http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/